# Load two depending datasets

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I load two datasets in the onCreate function of my activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
            }
    });
    mDatabase.child("events").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ...
                event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class);
                if (event.getHost().equals(currentUser.getId()) {
                      ....
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
            }
    });
    String name = currentUser.getName();
    ....
}
```

So I need some data of the users dataset in the events dataset. Most of the time this works, but since they are called async, they are sometimes loaded in the wrong order. So events is loaded before users is loaded.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee the order, you can nest the loading of the events into the callback for the user:

```
String name;
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            name = currentUser.getName();
            mDatabase.child("events").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        ...
                        event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class);
                        if (event.getHost().equals(currentUser.getId()) {
                              ....
                        }
                    }

                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
                    }
            });
        }

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
        }
});
```

The nesting becomes a bit deep, but if you pull the loading of events into a separate (named) method, that'll typically get better again.

Comment: There is no simple yes/no answer to that. They are not explicitly bad, but there are definitely cases where people nest their data and listeners too deeply. But first loading the user data to then load that user's events sounds reasonable, although it's more common to see [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) used for that.

Comment: I store some additional data in the users database, that I can't store in the default user dataset